# MissingError Template: web.external_layout

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to create a report in Odoo 12. But I come across an issue.

```
<template id="applicant_contract_offering_document">
    <t t-call="web.external_layout">
        <div class="header tahoma underline_bold center font_size_11">
            <p>OFFICIAL OFFERING LETTER</p>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="applicant_contract_offering">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="fhid_recruitment.applicant_contract_offering_document" />
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Odoo always gives me

```
Error to render compiling AST
MissingError: ('Record does not exist or has been deleted.\n\n(Records: [4], User:2)', None)
Template: web.external_layout
```

What am I missing? I can print without `web.external_layout` but it seems the CSS is not applied to the body of the report.

Comment: Does your module depend on `web`?

Comment: Previously not. But after I added `web` it is still has the same error. Don't worry I restarted server and upgraded my addons ;)

Comment: The weird part is I can call `web.html_container` even without depend to `web`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is very misleading. I urge every developer who encounter this kind of error message to try to check their codes again.

In my case, it was caused by empty record id.

Answer (score 0):

At the file `manifest.py` add `web` in the list of `dependencies`.